# How to properly transfer animation from After Effects to React Native?

Tags: react-native, after-effects

We have a project in After Effects with a file upload animation, and I would like to know how to most correctly transfer this to React Native?

We tried exporting to `mp4` or `gif`, but we need a transparent background and more control.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Lottie Animations](https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native), its simple and you can import AE projects.

Answer (score 0):

When making a transparent gif from an After Effects project I usually render out a Quicktime ProRes 4444 .mov file. (see image)  Then I import the mov into Photoshop and use File > Export > Save for Web.  Be sure to enable transparency, and set it to Loop Forever, assuming that's what you want.  It makes for much better quality gifs than from Ae, which I think the newest versions don't even support natively anymore.

Alternatively you might be able to convert the mov file into a webm (using ffmpeg or other 3rd party software) to retain the colors, since the gif file format only supports 256 colors, and also doesn't support semi-transparent pixels (such as outer glows).  I'm unsure if React Native supports webm files though, I'm just an After Effects guy.

[Ae export settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERVFw.png)
[Ps gif export settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rqK8I.png)